# Reduce all.js size in FontAwesome 5 (SVG w/ JS) with Webpack (in Django)

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, font-awesome

I'm using fontawesome-pro v. 5.14.0 in my application in addition to webpack to bundle up things into a `vendor.js` file.

I have an application that was originally developed using SVG with JS method of FontAwesome - but the size of `all.js` and even `all.min.js` is pretty gigantic weighing in at almost **6 MB** to load the entire JS file.

I'm trying to reduce the size of the `all.min.js` file by only loading the icons I need from it and have found people saying "use tree shaking", but cannot find any additional information or examples how to make that happen.

The layering functionality of FontAwesome is used in a number of spots throughout the application so I would prefer to continue utilizing SVG w/ JS.

I've tried importing just specific `.js` files I might need, but the layering only seems to work appropriately if I import `all.js`

Is there even a *way* to reduce it's file size? Or is the more appropriate option to just load the CSS and re-write the HTML?

From [this blog](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/npm/fontawesome-5-pro-npm-and-webpack-guide/) - I tried using this code (by putting it in my `index.js`) but it did not work:

```
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'

import { faUser, faPlus } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons'
import { faTwitter, faFacebookF } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(faUser, faPlus, faTwitter, faFacebookF)
```

I'm not sure how best to proceed or if it's even possible.

Comment: FontAwesome has [a few notes](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/other/tree-shaking) on how to go about tree-shaking. In short, it depends on webpack version and configuration to work. If the page does not help, edit your question to include details on how you use webpack.

Comment: Interesting question. I was expecting some file size improvements when importing just a couple of icons, but that wasn't the case.